# Flat, unramified base change preserves regularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Silverman's "Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves," and on page 337, he claims that if $C$ is a regular $R$-scheme, where $R$ is a DVR, then if $R^{sh}$ denotes the strict henselization of $R$, then $C \times_R R^{sh}$ is regular, because $C$ is regular and $R^{sh}/R$ is flat and unramified. I understand all the conditions being claimed are true, but I do not see why flat, unramified base change preserves regularity. Can someone either provide a reference or a detailed proof?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NG Answers your question, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this is off the unanswered list.

<strike>Note that $\mathrm{Spec}(R^\mathrm{sh})\to\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is faithfully flat (see [Tag 07QM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07QM)) so that $C_{R^\mathrm{sh}}\to C$ is faithfully flat. The claim then follows from [Tag 07NG](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07NG) which shows that if $Y\to X$ is faithfully flat, $X$ is regular, then so is $Y$.</strike>

**EDIT EDIT:** See the comments below—the EDIT is correct, I believe.

**EDIT:** After a more careful rereading of the question, I’d like to add that while the answer I supplied is ‘better’ in my opinion, it’s likely that Silverman meant something else. Namely, Silverman seems to be emphasizing the ‘ind-etale’ nature of $R\to R^\mathrm{sh}$. So, with this in mind here is an alternative proof.

Note that, by definition, we may write $R^\mathrm{sh}=\varinjlim R_i$ where each $R\to R_i$ is an etale map. So then, note that if $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\subseteq C$ is any affine open then

$$\mathrm{Spec}(A)_{R^\mathrm{sh}}=\mathrm{Spec}(\varinjlim (A\otimes_R R_i))$$,

and such affine schemes form an affine open cover of $C_{R^\mathrm{sh}}$. Thus, it suffices to show that each $\varinjlim(A\otimes_R R_i)$ is regular. But, the local rings of this colimit are of the form $\varinjlim (A\otimes_R R_i)_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ for $\mathfrak{p}_i$ compatible choices of primes of $A\otimes_R R_i$. But, such a ring is Noetherian (since $A\otimes_R R^\mathrm{sh}$ is finite type over $R^\mathrm{sh}$ which is Noetherian by [Tag 06LJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LJ)), and so by [Tag 07DX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07DX) it suffices to show that each $(A\otimes_R R_i)_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$ is regular or, in fact, just that $A\otimes_R R_i$ is regular. But, since $R\to R_i$ is etale, so is $A\to A\otimes_R R_i$, and so the claim follows from [Tag 025N](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/025N).

Again, I actually think this is an overly-complicated proof, but I wanted to address the direct implication that Silverman is making. I hope it’s helpful!

Comment: Hey Alex, isn't 07NG being applied in the wrong direction?

Comment: @MinseonShin Oh Jeeze, thanks Minseon! That’s pretty bad considering I’ve used this lemma several times (in the correct direction!!) in some papers. I guess it was late when I originally wrote that. Hopefully the edit argument is OK. Thanks for the good catch!